# Typing a nextjs HTTP method handler function in API routes correctly / Arbitrary number of generic parameters

Tags: typescript, next.js

I want to build a wrapper function for my API routes in NextJS, where I can pass multiple handlers for different HTTP methods into it.

Example usage: [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=55&ssc=2&pln=42&pc=1#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-EAOmwTxooFuYjKtGgeAXY07nyia7N25YKEwmFAli0NI0hfBIIjgicZAJkmKZpgA7rQNCGhYlimualo4HErjcq4ABq8RZNQZoWmUnqIigkK0L+0RaDwkiWNER4ouimK4nirjIcaqHEZacSgMGoDcvxoD4fE8TlMkPbmIQ-agCgODsEmCz2tojreiEOh6KQ7q4GpQQ+mEfrNMJQkCbhwl7IcxySOJwyJJJc5AVk9CZjmeZ2jo56XChrhEehpHlBJ5wLu894IFuJCUMQLAAIQfF837QCg0WdgSNDiLAeB+SRkg4AA2ipXlGlYAC6EC0I41BkDuiaWAg0jiOF56gAAkng4DNnqXCOIQFFbnBxxPAA-MF869jJA7ZRhBWed5XElTFHnaDpODlOO87rGN0myR6565MQWQACwAAwAKzlOeHQRFkBiXDg1y3LYAAGTGgJxVigAAJAYhVzVYHigGIkBkL+mCQHB4VPR4a3Besk5gkgEJQYmyapgOCFIcV3H+blABM0QkuYoSNFEsT6q4iKQKQxNGWTXAU4QJA000dMsMAABU55c+zwAEVNpG2A5dJksyQ22O92M5QTRO+iz+rxFydLsqL4tY2hUuU9Tsuk-Lis8irb1qzxZTRIijPMzrXAK8FHNc+ePOeEFMwmONsnyYp0DKQ6Xr6RprraaAHp6XUFsxITTPawgrPCZrEeGXLXAx+bkfRxzoB26APMCZZRwnLZIxCzOTkuVmVZLUVPkfMbuWBYX86hQg4UHruH5xSuAIIElKWxGldBiJlVc4-lv1Y2VEaVdVLC1fVjWWM1bUQJ1+o9X1oADREjgjc7C6u5N1fD7No+LSpK0w9vbibXOu+B7ge0kOkB0nedl2dDdd0PXcoAvQiiKGyhX0-UPihAGQMQZ-nBpDaG61TBw1BHA4Q7xxByXUIHSAjM7igh8GUPwLBw6h27KYT44D7j2CcDqBBYAEAYD1KAUcncSAiC6iwWO+DWS0ROAxB4ZDAYIFGGUWMoIIKQgAvVZKmAyAY2oBLdWGEbrBWpMybIJ8b6eidBpeO-o8GR3zvZUaphdr7RwFkXGx1joXSumIG6RCwa2CJHBE4m4iTQ1hnrd46U8CWEgLgQGwM14nFgPI5WRIlE6BWsHAyJMYgsO0UMAueiTDvE8eQXgRonBr0QtQG+2hzzFCsOweJN8+wDgMffPIxjjqHQunMRY0CTBw3KKCNxdA8BsHsZIWATgRCSOkfvXGcjt4KOCV7ZaKjwnqMidLOOkSdEENnCUh+RiTFmJftdAw1jIC2LaY45x28PCuLAO4gCXi8CgL8e0wJjJFHDLCT7EOkdTZUymUZGZddTCJMoBQOaaTJFZJyXkgp195llJMZU881Sz4X0dkAA)

```
interface GetResponse {
    hello: string,
}
// empty object
type PostResponse = Record<string, never>;

export default withMethodHandlers({
    "GET": (req, res: NextApiResponse<GetResponse>) => {
        res.status(200).json({hello: "world"})
    },
    // this does not work
    "POST": (req, res: NextApiResponse<PostResponse>) => {
        // do something with req.body
        return res.status(204).end();
    }

})
```

I have defined the function like so:

```
export enum HTTP_METHODS {
  "GET" = "GET",
  "POST" = "POST",
  "PUT" = "PUT",
  "DELETE" = "DELETE",
  "PATCH" = "PATCH",
}

type MethodHandler<T> = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<T>)=>void|Promise<void>;

function isObjKey<T>(key: PropertyKey, obj: T): key is keyof T {
    return key in obj;
}

//                                 v there could be up to HTTP_METHODS.length generics           v These can be all different
export function withMethodHandlers<T, U, V>(handlers: Partial<Record<HTTP_METHODS, MethodHandler<T | U | V>>>){
    return async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<T | U | V | ApiError>) => {
        if(isObjKey(req.method, handlers)){
            // need to use ! here because TS thinks handlers[req.method] might be undefined. Is my typeguard wrong?
            return handlers[req.method]!(req, res);
        }
        return res.status(405).json({message: `HTTP Method ${req.method} not allowed`});
    }
}
```

My problem is that I would like to keep this as generic as possible. So I am aware that I could write it like

```
export function withMethodHandlers2<GetResponseType, PostResponseType, PutResponseType /*...*/>(handlers: {
    "GET"?: MethodHandler<GetResponseType>,
    "POST"?: MethodHandler<PostResponseType>,
    "PUT"?: MethodHandler<PutResponseType>,
    /*...*/
}){
    return async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<GetResponseType | PostResponseType | PutResponseType /* ... */| ApiError>) => {
        if(isObjKey(req.method, handlers)){
            // need to use ! here because TS thinks handlers[req.method] might be undefined. Is my typeguard wrong?
            return handlers[req.method]!(req, res);
        }
        return res.status(405).json({message: `HTTP Method ${req.method} not allowed`});
    }
}
```

but that seems rather verbose. Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: I'm thinking through the same problem. It's challenging with TypeScript to combine all the handlers for each http method in one route, even though that's the REST convention.

Answer (score 2):

This middleware accomplishes what you're trying to do without needing any generics to keep track of the response type. You can simply specify the response type where each http method handler is defined.

I am using an enum for `HttpMethod` in this example, but you could replace that with a generic if you wanted.

**Middleware**

```js
export const withHttpMethods = (
  handlers: Partial<
    Record<HttpMethod, (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => Promise<unknown> | undefined>
  >
) => {
  return async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const method = req.method as HttpMethod | undefined;
    if (!method) {
      res
        .status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST)
        .setHeader(HttpResponseHeader.Error, 'No HTTP method specified')
        .end();
      return;
    }

    const handler = handlers[method];
    if (!handler) {
      res
        .status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST)
        .setHeader(
          HttpResponseHeader.Error,
          'No handler specified for HTTP method'
        )
        .end();
      return;
    }

    return handler(req, res);
  };
};
```

**Usage**

```js
export default withHttpMethods({
[HttpMethod.GET]: (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<YourTypeHere>) => { ... }
})
```